# Spark structured streaming vs Kafka consumer/producer

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have use case where my application needs to read studentids and other related info from a Kafka topic and insert as a record for each studentid in Postgres database
There will be maximum few thousands of studentids per day

I’m thinking of creating a Java based Kafka consumer application to read and process message from a Kafka topic

Should I consider spark structured streaming with Kafka  or general java based Kafka consumer for this usecase

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the answer to your question, but rather the reinventing the wheel you should use already existing tools: **Apache Kafka Connect**.

Kafka Connect is a tool for scalably and reliably streaming data between Apache Kafka and other systems. Several of connectors are developed and ready to use. There is also an option to developed your own.

For your use case - ingesting data to Postgres - there is already developed connector by Confluent: [JDBC Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html)

More details regarding whole concept of Kafka Connect can be found:

- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect
- https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html

Answer (score 0):

From your use case it sounds like:

- The scale of your data is small (just a few thousands users)
- The volume of your data is consistent
- You’re not transforming/manipulating/aggregating that data in anyway but pretty
  much just reading it as input from Kafka and writing as output to a
  Postgres table.

Bottom line I think Spark won’t give you a single advantage and even provide an unnecessary overhead.